# A logical way to compare an array of csv file paths to an array of specified project names

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, wxpython

I'm looking for a logical way to compare a csv list of projects from the user to an array of file paths I generate with glob. It however does not have to happen specifically that way, I just need to take a csv list file of projects and work on them.

```
CsvScrape = glob.glob('C:\Ryans_Copy_Test\*\*DATA.CSV')

            for scrape_items in CsvScrape:
                print scrape_items

            CsvReader = csv.reader(open(CsvBrowse, 'rb'), dialect=csv.excel)

            for reader_items in CsvReader:
                print reader_items
```

it's not really much yet, but what I had planned was to generate a list of *DATA.CSV files and then match my list of csv projects to them.. I'm running into issues like how would I do a proper comparison (do I strip my glob list of file path info then compare the items, etc) how do I tell the user the project name they entered is not found, etc..

I'm having some trouble explaining what I'm trying to accomplish so if I need to elaborate more on a particular items just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: tip: change `'C:\Ryans_Copy_Test\*\*DATA.CSV'` to `r'C:\Ryans_Copy_Test\*\*DATA.CSV'` to avoid accidental backslash escaping

Comment: This would be my sample data -> http://pastebin.com/Hwzds0k3 and here is my code -> http://pastebin.com/vwqg0QeF

Comment: My end goal is to compare the files in the glob list to my user submitted csv list. what ever matches I want to move with os.copyfile to another location. Any projects that the user submitted with their csv file that did not match to my glob list will be outputted to inform them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If glob returns full pathnames:

`scrape_items = map(os.path.basename, scrape_items)`

Your `reader_items` is probably going to be a list of a list:

`reader_items = [row[0] for row in reader_items]`

Use sets to find what's not there:

`not_in_csv = set(reader_items).difference(scrape_items)`

Comment: Anon do you mind explaining scrape_items = map(os.path.basename, scrape_items) and reader_items = [row[0] for row in reader_items], I'm not really tracking. I do however follow on comparing with sets.

Comment: They are variations of "apply a function to every element of the list"; maybe you've seen

`basename_scrape_items = []
for item in scrape_items:
basename_scrape_items.append(os.path.basename(item))`

`map` is called a higher-order function. It calls `os.path.basename` on every element of `scrape_items` and returns it.

The brackets, called a list comprehension, does the same thing, but is considered more "pythonic".
It means `[<do something to item> for <item> in list]`, and the whole list is returned, processed.

You might have to do that kind, or other kinds of processing on your input.

Comment: You sir win, thank you for the help.. It did in fact strip the file path from my glob item list. At this point I just need to compare basename_scrape_items to my reader_items and select the matches.

Answer (score 0):

How close would be the project name to the csv file name? Would you need regex to do the job or is it expected to be just PROJECT_NAMEDATA.CSV? Because in that case you would be just talking about:

```
if os.path.basename(scrape_items)[:-8] == reader_items: 
    pass
```

Comment: it would be C:\path\to\file\differs\ [someprojectname] DATA.CSV

Comment: I'm done for today but I think with the answer below from anonymous and these two modifications, it should work:scrape_items = map(os.path.basename, scrape_items)
scrape_items = map(lambda x: x[:-8].upper(),scrape_items)

Comment: I appreciate the help so far damian